# How to compute $\int_{2/\pi}^{+\infty }\ln\cos(1/x)\,dx$?

Tags: improper-integrals

What it says in the title.
 If $$I=\int_{2/\pi}^{+\infty }\ln\left({\cos\left({\frac{1}{x} }\right) }\right) \, \mathrm dx,$$ how could I proceed in order to find the value of $I$?

Comment: Do you know there is a closed form?

Comment: I am pretty sure there is.

Comment: First step is to put $u=1/x$, I'd say.

Comment: Is the question just "does it converge"? or do you actually need to find the value?

Comment: Indeed, then I have $I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2} }\frac{\ln(\cos(u))}{u^{2}}du$
But what can I do with it?

Comment: I need the value.

Comment: wolframalpha times out computing the exact value, but if you replace $\infty$ with 100000000 it seems to have converged to about $-1.03294$.  So it looks like it probably actually converges... considering that wolframalpha fails to find a closed form, I suspect it will be very hard to do so.

Comment: If you substitute $y = 1/x$ and then $z = \cos y$ then you should get the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln z dz}{(\cos^{-1} z)^2 \sqrt{1-z^2}}.$ Wolfram Alpha numerically integrates this to -1.03294 but doesn't find a closed form solution. I can't tell you if there is one or not, but it looks like it converges.

Comment: @Travis: Wolfram doesn't find a close form of $\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\cos(x))dx$ and yet it's very easy to compute this integral and find $\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\cos(x))dx=-\frac{\pi\ln(2)}{2}$. Therefore your argument is not valide ! :-)

Comment: @Surb, my argument is more of a heuristic... plus, I don't think I see the easy way to compute the integral you describe (not immediately at least).

Comment: The little astuce of the integral I proposed is simply to show that $\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\cos(t))dt=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin(t))dt$ and thus that $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\cos(t))dt=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(\cos(t))dt+ \int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin(t))dt\right)=...$$ It's of course not obvious, but when you know the trick it's not complicate :-) What I wanted to say is that wolfram is not enough to justify that there is not any close form. I know that it's not what you wanted to say directly, but it looks like you thought about that :-) Good evening,

Comment: @Surb The integral of interest is not $\int_0^{\pi/2}\log \cos x dx$.  Rather, it is $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\log \cos x}{x^2} dx$

Comment: @alkabary Please avoid edits *worsening* the readability of the question: using `\frac{2}{\pi}` instead of `2/\pi`, and `\large`, were two *bad* ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a change of variable and [a well-known fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292468/fourier-series-of-log-sine-and-log-cos):
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\log\cos x}{x^2}\,dx=2\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{\sin(kx)}{x}\right)^2\,dx\tag{1}$$
but since:
$$ \cos x = \prod_{n\geq 0}\left(1-\frac{4x^2}{(2n+1)^2\pi^2}\right)\tag{2}$$
we have:
$$ \log \cos x = -\sum_{n\geq 0}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{4^m x^{2m}}{m(2n+1)^{2m}\pi^{2m}}=-\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(4^m-1)\zeta(2m)}{m\,\pi^{2m}}x^{2m}\tag{3}$$
so the RHS of $(1)$ also equals:
$$ -\frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(1-4^{-m})\zeta(2m)}{ m(2m-1)}\tag{4}$$
that is a fast convergent series.

Comment: @Dr.MV: I found another mistake, it was in $(3)$. Now everything should be right.

Comment: I found it!!  Thanks