# Closed-form of $\int_0^1 \operatorname{Li}_3\left(1-x^2\right) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions, closed-form, polylogarithm

By using dilogarithm functional equations we can show that
$$
\int_0^1 \operatorname{Li}_2\left(1-x^2\right)\,dx = \frac{\pi^2}{2}-4,
$$
where $\operatorname{Li}_2$ is the [dilogarithm function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html).

Could we evaluate in closed-form the following integral?

> $$
> I = \int_0^1 \operatorname{Li}_3\left(1-x^2\right)\,dx,
> $$

where $\operatorname{Li}_3$ is the [trilogarithm function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trilogarithm.html).

A related integral with known closed-form is
$$\int_0^1 \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\,dx = \zeta(3)+\frac{\pi^2}{3}-8\ln2 - 4\pi\,i,$$
where $\zeta$ is the [Riemann zeta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html).

Comment: I doubt that the integral admits a closed form, because there exists a functional equation to simplify $Li_2(1-x^2)$ but this isn't the case for the trilogarithm.

Comment: another approach would be to expand the integral to an infinite series $$I=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{2n}}{n^3(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}$$ and then calculate definite integrals of $\arcsin^2 x$ ,which has similar series representation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$-\frac72\zeta\left(3\right)+\pi^2\left(\ln 2-1\right)+8$$

Comment: Nice but how did you arrived here sir ?

Comment: @RenatoFaraone Namagiri was actually looking for Kleo, but found only L.G.

Comment: Probably it was repeated integration by parts. By this way the problem boils down to integrate the product of $\left(-x-\frac{1}{2}\log(1-x)+\frac{1}{2}\log(1+x)\right)$ and $\frac{x\log x}{1-x^2}$.

Comment: Using differentiation under the integral sign, that boils down to evaluating a few derivatives of a Beta function, not that hard.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Feel free to post your solution. Thank you L.G. for your answer. +1.

Answer (score 14):

Expanding my comment: the substitution $1-x^2\mapsto x$, followed by expanding the trilogarithm and keeping in mind Legrende's duplication formula $B(n+1,\frac12)=2^{2n+1}B(n+1,n+1)$, we arrive at $$I=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{2n}}{n^3(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{2n}}{n^3\binom{2n}{n}}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{2n+1}}{n^2(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}\\=4\int_0^1\frac{\arcsin^2x}{x}\,dx-4\int_0^1\arcsin^2x \,dx$$
where I used the fact that  $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}}=2\arcsin^2x$.

The second integral is easily evaluated by IBP twice: $$\int_0^1\arcsin^2x \,dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x^2\cos x \,dx=\frac{\pi^2}{4}-2$$

The first integral may be evaluated by IBP and using [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292468/fourier-series-of-log-sine-and-log-cos) $\displaystyle -\ln\sin x=\ln2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2nx)}{n}$:
$$\begin{align} \int_0^1\frac{\arcsin^2x}{x}\,dx\\&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x^2\cot x \,dx\\&=-2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\ln\sin x \,dx\\
&=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\left(\ln2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2nx)}{n}\right)\,dx\\&=\frac{\pi^2}{4}\ln2+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\cos(2nx)\,dx\\&=\frac{\pi^2}{4}\ln2+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n}\frac1{4n^2}((-1)^n-1)\\&=\frac{\pi^2}{4}\ln2-\frac{7}{8}\zeta(3).
\end{align}$$

Comment: Well Done!  A big +1!

Answer (score 9):

To prove L.G. result, one just needs to apply twice integration by parts, then prove through its favourite technique (for instance, differentiation under the integral sign and computation of a few derivatives of a Beta function) that:
$$I_0=\int_{0}^{1}x^2 \log(x)\,\frac{dx}{1-x^2}=1-\frac{\pi^2}{8}, $$
$$I_{-}=\int_{0}^{1}x \log(x)\log(1-x)\,\frac{dx}{1-x^2}=\frac{\pi^2\log(4)-5\zeta(3)}{16}, $$
$$I_{+}=\int_{0}^{1}x \log(x)\log(1+x)\,\frac{dx}{1-x^2}=\frac{-\pi^2\log(4)+9\zeta(3)}{16}. $$
More details to come if wanted. Time to go to bed for me.

Comment: Thank you. +1. If you have time for that, it would be nice to see your complete solution. Good night.

Comment: I worked on this and got as far as the second integration by parts.  The two offending terms were $$\int_0^1x \log(x)\frac{\log(1\pm x)}{1\mp x}\,dx$$and I abandoned shortly thereafter due to time constraints ...

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^1\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x^2)\ dx\overset{IBP}{=}2\int_0^1\frac{x^2\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x^2)}{1-x^2}\ dx\\
&=2\int_0^1\left(\frac1{1-x^2}-1\right)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x^2)\ dx\\
&=2\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x^2)}{1-x^2}\ dx-2\int_0^1\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x^2)\ dx\tag{1}
\end{align}
By the OP, the second integral is $\boxed{\frac{\pi^2}{2}-4}$.

To calculate the first integral, we are going to use the generalized integral expression of the polylogrithmic function which can be found in the book ***(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums and series*** page 4.

$$\int_0^1\frac{x\ln^n(u)}{1-xu}\ du=(-1)^n n!\operatorname{Li}_{n+1}(x)$$ and by setting $n=1$ and replacing $x$ with $1-x^2$ we get

$$\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{2}(1-x^2)}{1-x^2}=-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(u)}{1-ux+ux^2}\ du$$

Now we can write

$$\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x^2)}{1-x^2}\ dx=-\int_0^1\ln u\left(\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1-ux+ux^2}\right)\ du$$

$$=-\int_0^1\ln u\left(\frac{\arctan\sqrt{\frac{u}{1-u}}}{\sqrt{u-u^2}}\right)\ du, \quad \color{red}{\arctan\sqrt{\frac{u}{1-u}}=\arcsin\sqrt{u}=x}$$

$$=-4\int_0^{\pi/2}x\ln(\sin x)\ dx=-4\left(\frac7{16}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^2}{8}\ln2\right)=\boxed{\frac{\pi^2}{2}\ln2-\frac74\zeta(3)}$$

where the last result follows from the Fourier series of $\ln(\sin x)=-\ln2-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \cos(2nx)}{n}$.

Plugging the boxed results of the two integrals in $(1)$, we get

> $$I=\pi^2\left(\ln 2-1\right)-\frac72\zeta\left(3\right)+8$$

---

**Note:** Since $$\arctan x=-\frac{i}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1+ix}{1-ix}\right)$$

Then 
\begin{align}
\arctan\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}&=-\frac{i}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1+\frac{ix}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}{1-\frac{ix}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\right)\\
&=-\frac{i}{2}\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}+ix}{\sqrt{1-x^2}-ix}*\color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}+ix}{\sqrt{1-x^2}+ix}}\right)\\
&=-\frac{i}{2}\ln\left(\frac{(\sqrt{1-x^2}+ix)^2}{1}\right)\\
&=-i\ln\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}+ix\right)\\
&=\arcsin x
\end{align}

and if we replace $x$ with $\sqrt{x}$, we get

$$\arctan\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}=\arcsin\sqrt{x}$$

---

**Here is a different proof**:

Since $$\frac{d}{dy}\arctan\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}=\frac1{\sqrt{1-y^2}}$$

Then $$\left.\arctan\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\right|_0^x=\int_0^x\frac1{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\ dy$$

$$\arctan\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\arcsin x$$