# Integrating $\ln(\tan^2(x) + 1)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How do I integrate the following function? $$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\ln(\tan^2 x+1) \; dx$$

Comment: Thank you but I think that it must be a solution without Catalan's constant.

Comment: I don't know a way of expressing the Catalan constant in other constants. Why do you think there must be a way?

Comment: This problem is from a book for 12th students and I don't learn anything about this constant at class

Comment: Maybe there should be $\frac{\pi}{2}$ instead of $\frac{\pi}{4}$? Otherwise I don't think you can get away with it without catalan constant

Comment: The book says it's pi/4...

Comment: Is there an answer in your book?

Comment: Unfortunately not for this problem:)

Comment: Well, there is not much to do, the answer for this integral is $\frac{\pi}{2}\log 2-G$, where $G$ is the Catalan number.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\log(\tan^2(x)+1)\,dx = -2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\log(\cos\theta)\,d\theta $$
then exploiting the [Fourier expansion of $\log(\cos\theta)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292468/fourier-series-of-log-sine-and-log-cos) it follows that:

> $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\log(\tan^2(x)+1)\,dx =\color{red}{-K+\frac{\pi}{2}\,\log 2}$$
>   where $K$ is [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_constant).