# How to evaluate $\int_0^\pi(\ln(\sin(x)))^2 \, dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms

To find: $$\int_0^\pi(\ln(\sin(x)))^2 \, dx$$  Tried changing limits and adding, also tried using complex numbers but failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

write $\sin(x)^a=e^{a\log(\sin(x))}$

Then
$$
I=\partial_a^2 \left. \int_0^\pi dx\sin^a(x) \right|_{a=0}
$$

This integral can be evaluated in terms of [Euler's Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals) and yields after simplification

$$
I=\sqrt{\pi }\partial_a^2 \left. \left(\frac{ \Gamma \left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{a}{2}+1\right)}\right) \right|_{a=0}
$$

calculating the derivatives and taking the limit as $a\rightarrow 0$
is a little bit exhausting, but finally  yields an result (best use a CAS),

> $$
> I=\frac{\pi ^3}{12}+\pi  \log ^2(2)
> $$

Essentially the limit follows from the [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) that:
$$
 \psi_0\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=-\gamma-2\log(2),\quad
\psi_1\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{2},\quad \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}
$$

and

$$
\partial_x \Gamma(x)=\Gamma(x) \psi_0(x), \quad \partial_x \psi_0(x)=\psi_1(x)
$$

where $ \psi_{0/1}(x)$ is the Di/Trigamma function and $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Comment: Thanks, just required this.

Comment: @ShakulPathak , Thanks, i added a bit of context how to perform the last step of the calculation

Comment: Perhaps a link to [Wallis' integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals) would also be in order.

Comment: @Lucian , you're right, done!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a faster way to recover tired's result is to apply [Parseval's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval's_identity) to the [Fourier series of $\log\sin x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292468/fourier-series-of-log-sine-and-log-cos).