# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{1} \ln \left( \sec \left( \frac{\pi x}{2} \right) \right) \ln (\sin (\pi x)) \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Other than being generally interested in this integral, it also appears in my $\zeta$ approach to my [question here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4194966/is-it-possible-to-evaluate-int-01-ln-sin-pi-x-ln-gamma-x2)

Is it possible to evaluate the following integral? I was thinking to perhaps use an infinite product approach for $\sec$, however, I couldn’t really get far with it.
$$\int_{0}^{1} \ln \left( \sec \left( \frac{\pi x}{2} \right) \right) \ln (\sin (\pi x)) \, dx$$

If this integral is possible, is it also possible to evaluate the following two other integrals?
$$\int_{0}^{1} \ln \left( \sec \left( \frac{\pi x}{2} \right) \right)^2 \ln (\sin (\pi x)) \, dx$$
$$\int_{0}^{1} x \ln \left( \sec \left( \frac{\pi x}{2} \right) \right) \ln (\sin (\pi x)) \, dx$$

Comment: For the first one, substitute $ y = \pi x /2$ and use double angle formula of sine. After that, it's easy.

Comment: Ah, I’m silly for not realising how trivial these integrals were; the thought of using the double angle formulae never crossed my mind...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substitute  $t= \frac{\pi x}{2} $ to get $$-\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\cos t) \ln(\sin 2t) \ dt \\ = -\frac{2\ln 2}{\pi} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(\cos t) \ dt -\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(\sin t)\ln(\cos t) \ dt-\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\ln(\cos t))^2 \ dt$$ Now, using the results for

[$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(\cos t) \ dt$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690644/evaluate-int-0-pi-2-log-cosx-mathrmdx)

[$$ \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(\sin t) \ln(\cos t) \ dt $$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492878/find-int-0-frac-pi2-ln-sinx-ln-cosx-mathrm-dx?noredirect=1)

[$$ \int_0^{\pi} (\ln(\sin t))^2 \ dt $$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1467430/how-to-evaluate-int-0-pi-ln-sinx2-dx?noredirect=1) (as $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\ln(\cos t))^2 \ dt = \frac 12  \int_0^{\pi} (\ln(\sin t))^2 \ dt  $), the original integral evaluates to $$-\frac{\pi^2}{24} -(\ln 2)^2 $$