# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(n)}{n}=e^{-\pi}?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was trying to empirically estimate the very slowly convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(n)}{n}$ and it seems like it converges to $e^{-\pi}$ or $\pi^{-\pi}$. Does anyone know of any theoretical answer to summing this series?

Comment: i think neither of your conjectures is right: [$e^\pi$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+sum+E^Pi+cos%28n%29%2Fn) and [$\pi^\pi$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+sum+Pi^Pi+cos%28n%29%2Fn)

Comment: Mathematica says it equals $-\frac{1}{2}(\log(1-e^i)+\log((e^i-1)e^{-i})$

Comment: The value of such a series can also be computed by exploiting the Fourier series of $\log|\sin(x/2)|$ - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292468/fourier-series-of-log-sine-and-log-cos

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the power series for $\log(1+x)$ and $\operatorname{Re}(\log(z))=\log\left(\left|z\right|\right)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(n)}n
&=\operatorname{Re}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{in}}n\right)\\
&=\operatorname{Re}\left(-\log\left(1-e^i\right)\right)\\[6pt]
&=-\log\left(\sqrt{2-2\cos(1)}\right)\\[6pt]
&=-\log\left(2\sin(1/2)\right)\\[9pt]
&\doteq0.0420195
\end{align}
$$
whereas $e^{-\pi}\doteq0.0432139$.

As achille hui mentions in a comment, the convergence of the series is guaranteed by [Abel's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_test#Abel.27s_test_in_complex_analysis).

Comment: How do you justify the second equality?

Comment: @Wojowu: the power series for $\log(1+x)$

Comment: Woops, I meant the third equality.

Comment: +1 for you. Note that Mathematica's answer can actually be simplified to this with just a couple of steps. I'm surprised Mathematica left it in the form it gave.

Comment: Personally, I will use [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem) to justify the summation of series equal to $\Re(-\log(1-e^{i}))$ for points on the circle of convergence.

Comment: so, sum(cos(n))=1/2? note that realpart(1/(1-exp(i*x)))=1/2 for all x

Comment: @TroyMcClure: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\cos(nx)$ does not converge. However, $$\begin{align} \lim_{r\to1^-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n\cos(nx) &=\lim_{r\to1^-}\operatorname{Re}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^ne^{inx}\right)\\ &=\lim_{r\to1^-}\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac1{1-re^{ix}}\right)\\ &=\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac1{1-e^{ix}}\right)\\
&=\frac12 \end{align}$$