# Closed form of $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{\sin n}n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

What is the closed form of
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\sin n}n$$?

---

My approach:

$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\sin n}n=\Im\left[\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{e^{in}}n\right]=\Im\left[-\text{Log}(1-e^{i})\right]$$ where $\text{Log}(1):=0$.

$$\Im\left[-\text{Log}(1-e^i)\right]=-\arg(1-e^i)=-\frac{1-\pi}2$$

Thus,
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\sin n}n=\frac{\pi-1}2$$

And as a bonus,
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\cos n}n=\ln(2\sec1)$$

---

Is this correct?

Comment: yes, it's correct

Comment: The former sum is correct, but for the latter I find $-\frac{1}{2}\log(2 - 2\cos(1)) = -\log(2 \sin(1/2))$ which differs from what you got (maybe a typo?). See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1612163/147873

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluation of Sum of $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (n)}{n}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879726/evaluation-of-sum-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac-sin-nn) See also: [Evaluate $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \ n}{ n } $ using the fourier series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630796/evaluate-sum-n-1-infty-frac-sin-n-n-using-the-fourier-series) ; [How to prove $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)}n=\frac{\pi-1}2$ using only real numbers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2031572/how-to-prove-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac-sinnn-frac-pi-12-using-only)