# How to calculate $\int_0^\pi \ln(1+\sin x)\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, closed-form

How to calculate this integral
$$\int_0^\pi \ln(1+\sin x)\mathrm dx$$
I didn't find this question in the previous questions. With the help of Wolframalpha I got an answer $-\pi \ln 2+4\mathbf{G}$, where $\mathbf{G}$ denotes Catalan's Constant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First we rewrite $\log(1+\sin(x))=\log(2)+2\log(\sin(x/2+\pi/4))$. This yields, after shifting $x/2+\pi/4\rightarrow y,dx\rightarrow 2 dy$

$$
I=\pi\log(2)+4\underbrace{\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}\log(\sin(y))dy}_{J}
$$

Now we might employ the [Fourier series of $\log(\sin(x))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292468/fourier-series-of-log-sine-and-log-cos) to calculate $J$

$$
J=-\log(2)\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}dy-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}\cos(2yk)dy=\\
-\frac{\pi}{2}\log(2)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}
$$

where we used $\sin(\frac{3\pi}{2} k)-\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} k)=(-1)^{k}-(-1)^{k+1}=2(-1)^k$ in the second line.

Employing  [the series representation of the Catalan constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_constant) we find

$$
J=-\frac{\pi}{2}\log(2)+G
$$

and therefore

> $$
> I=\pi \log(2)+J=-\pi \log(2)+4G \quad (*)
> $$

---

Just for fun, lets see what contour integration can do.
We again use $J$ rewriting it by the help of the identity $\log(\sin(x))=\log(i/2)-ix+\log(1-e^{2 i x})$. The integral over the first two terms is trivial leaving us with

$$
J=-\frac{\pi}{2}\log(2)+\underbrace{\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}\log(1-e^{2 i x})}_{K}
$$

to evaluate $K$ we integrate the complex valued function

$$
f(z)=\log(1-e^{2 i z})
$$

over an rectangle $C$ in the complex plane with verticies $(\pi/4,3\pi/4,3\pi/4+i R,\pi/4+i R)$ where in the end we want to take the limit  $R\rightarrow +\infty$. As one can easily check, the contribution from the top of the rectangle vanishs (the integrand vanishs as $\mathcal{O}(e^{-2R})$ for big $R$). Furthermore the integrand is holomorphic inside the contour of integration and therefore we can express the integral of interest in terms of the vertical pieces of the contour

$$
\int_C f(z)dz=K+i\int_{0}^{\infty}\log(1+ie^{-2y})dy-i\int_{0}^{\infty}\log(1-ie^{-2y})dy=0
$$

this can be simplified to

$$
K=2\int_0^{\infty}\arctan(e^{-2y})dy=\int_0^{\infty}\arctan(e^{-y})dy
$$

using the [series repesentation of arctan](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arkustangens_und_Arkuskotangens), we may easily conclude that this integral is equal to $G$ and therefore

> $$
> K=G
> $$

from which it follows that

$$
J=-\frac{\pi}{2}\log(2)+K=-\frac{\pi}{2}\log(2)+G$$

from which (*) follows immediatly

Comment: The value of $J$ is $-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2+G$. And maybe the second line of your answer is not correct.

Comment: @EvilNebula. Ok, was a tiny bit too fast in the beginning...now everything should be fine! Thx

Comment: @EvilNebula
there is also a possibiliy to integrate this by contour methods, just in case u are interested

Comment: I tried some other approaches, but this one was the more efficient than any other one.  So, a big +1 ... should be a +2 ... Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV thank u very much, i added a proof using contour integration which i personally like the most :)

Comment: Tired.  For the contour integral, the initial limits are from $\pi/4$ to $3\pi/4$, yet you had written $0$ to $\infty$.  I hope you don't mind my editing it. - Mark

Comment: @tired (+1)Excellent solution! Thank you tired!