# How to compute this integral using residues.

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I want to prove that

$$\int_0^1 \log(\sin(\pi x))dx=-\log(2)$$

using the below contour [image]

So,I was trying with $f(z)= \log(\sin(\pi z))$ but I don't know how to compute the residue at $z=0$. The other function I picked was $f(z)=e^{-i \pi z}$ and since it is periodic with period $1$ we have that the integral over $\gamma_1$ and the one over $\gamma_2$  will cancel but the integral over $\gamma_3$ is not the one I want to compute, but in fact I think this didn't work since in this case $f$ is entire.

Another idea I had was to use the definition of the logarithm of a function but I don't know how to extract the desire integral from that information.

Can someone help me with this issue please?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You can actually compute this integral with just elementary calculus, but I'll see if I can work out a way to do it with residues

Comment: Right :) the idea is to use residues :)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672030/how-to-calculate-int-0-pi-ln1-sin-x-mathrm-dx/1672067#1672067 u can follow the ideas i used in the link above

Comment: Ok let me check that out :) just a second

Comment: Well, is not that clear since the integration uses a lot some properties of the given function :(

Comment: what exactly is unclear?

Comment: Just give me some minutes :) and I'll tell you

Comment: Well the first thing is the change of the contour and obviously you use that in the integral 