# Narrower the limits harder the integral!

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, catalans-constant

When I met the integral $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln (1+\sin x-\cos x) d x$, I evaluated it by squaring $ 1+\sin x -\cos x.
$
$ \begin{aligned}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln (1+\sin x-\cos x) d x&=\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln (1+\sin x-\cos x)^{2} d x \\&=\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln [2(1+\sin x-\cos x-\sin x \cos x)] d x \\&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln 2 d x+ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln [(1+\sin x)(1-\cos x)] d x\right]\end{aligned} \tag*{} $
Now we deal with the last integral
$ \displaystyle \begin{aligned}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln [(1+\sin x)(1-\cos x)] d x&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln (1+\sin x) d x+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln (1-\cos x) d x \\&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln (1+\cos x) d x+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln (1-\cos x) d x \\&=\left.\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln \left(1-\cos ^{2} x\right) d x\right.\\&=2 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln (\sin x) d x \quad \textrm{ (By my post in Footnote )}\\&=2\left(-\frac{\pi}{2} \ln 2\right)\\&=-\pi \ln 2\end{aligned} \tag*{} $
We can now conclude that
$\displaystyle \boxed{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln (1+\sin x-\cos x) d x=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} \ln 2-\pi \ln 2\right)=-\frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2 } \tag*{} $

---

Then I want to find the integral with narrow width $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Similarly, we have
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln (1+\sin x-\cos x) d x =\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{\pi}{4}\ln 2 + \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln [(1+\sin x)(1-\cos x)] d x\right] $$

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln [(1+\sin x)(1-\cos x)] d x=  \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln (1+\sin x) d x+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln (1-\cos x) d x $$

---

\begin{aligned}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln (1-\cos x) d x&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln \left(2 \sin ^{2} \frac{x}{2}  \right) d x \\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}[\ln 2+2 \ln (\sin \frac{x}{2})] d x \\
&=\frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2+4 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{8}} \ln (\sin x) d x \\
\end{aligned}

However, I am stuck in this integral and $ \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln (1+\sin x) d x$.  Your help and suggestion is highly appreciated.

---

Footnote:
My [post](https://artisticmathematics.quora.com/Daily-Question-23-2-2021-Evaluate-the-Integral-math-displaystyle-int_-0-frac-pi-2-ln-sin-x-dx-math).

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672030/how-to-calculate-int-0-pi-ln1-sin-x-mathrm-dx) may be useful.

Comment: [In terms of](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+ln%281%2Bsin+x%29&dataset=) $f(x):=\int_0^x\ln(1+\sin t)dt$,$$\begin{align}\int_0^x\ln(1-\sin t)dt&=-f(-x)\\\implies\int_0^x\ln(1-\cos t)dt&=f(x-\pi/2)-f(-\pi/2)\\\implies\int_0^x\ln(1+\sin t-\cos t)dt&=\frac12[x\ln2+f(x)+f(x-\pi/2)-f(-\pi/2)]\\\implies\int_0^{\pi/4}\ln(1+\sin t-\cos t)dt&=\frac12\left[\frac{\pi\ln2}{4}+f(\pi/4)+f(-\pi/4)-f(-\pi/2)\right].\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

Starting from the beginning, using the tangent half-angle substitution  $$I=\int\log \big[1+\sin (x)-\cos (x)\big]\, d x=2\int \frac{\log \left(\frac{2 t (t+1)}{t^2+1}\right)}{t^2+1}\,dt$$ Expanding the numerator
$$\frac{\log \left(\frac{2 t (t+1)}{t^2+1}\right)}{t^2+1}=\frac{\log(2)}{t^2+1}+\frac{\log(t)+\log(t+1)-\log(t+i)-\log(t-i) }{(t+i)(t-i)}$$ Use also
$$\frac 1{(t+i)(t-i)}=\frac i 2 \left(\frac{1}{t+i}-\frac{1}{t-i}\right)$$ So, we face a bunch of integrals looking like
$$\int \frac {\log (t+a)}{t+b}\,dt=\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a+t}{a-b}\right)+\log (a+t) \log \left(\frac{b+t}{b-a}\right)$$

Back to $x$,the antiderivative is
$$I=i \left(\text{Li}_2\left(i e^{i x}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(e^{i x}\right)+\frac{1 }{2}x^2\right)+x \log
   \left(\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) (\sin (x)+i \cos (x))\right)$$

Now, for
$$J(t)=\int_0^t\log \big[1+\sin (x)-\cos (x)\big]\, d x$$ we have
$$J(0)=-C+\frac{7 \pi ^2}{48}\,i$$

Now, making $t=\frac \pi n$

$$K_n=\int_0^{\frac \pi n }\log \big[1+\sin (x)-\cos (x)\big]\, d x$$ gives
$$K_1=2 C-\frac{1}{2} \pi  \log (2) \qquad \qquad K_2=-\frac{1}{4} \pi  \log (2)$$
$$K_4=C-\frac{1}{8} \pi  \log (2)-\frac{\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)+\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)-\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(\frac{5}{8}\right)-\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)}{32 \sqrt{2}}$$

I did not find any other looking nice.

Expanded as series
$$K_n=k \log(k)+\sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^n\, a_n\, k^n \qquad \text{with} \qquad k=\frac \pi n$$ and the first coefficients are
$$\left\{1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{7}{72},\frac{1}{48},\frac{121}{14400},\frac{1}{288},\cdots\right\}$$

Limited to these terms, the relative error is less than $0.001$% as soon as $n\geq 5$.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by Claude, I try to find its indefinite integral.
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \int \ln (1+\sin x-\cos x) d x = & \int \ln \left(2 \sin ^2 \frac{x}{2}+2 \sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2}\right) d x \\
= & \int \ln 2 d x+\int \ln \left(\sin \frac{x}{2}\right) d x+\int\ln \left(\sin \frac{x}{2}+\cos \frac{x}{2}\right) d x \\
= & x \ln 2+\int \ln (\sin \frac{x}{2}  ) d x+\frac{1}{2} \int \ln \left(1+\sin x\right)dx
\end{aligned}
$$

---

$$
\begin{aligned}\int \ln \left(2 \sin \frac{x}{2}\right) d x=&\int \ln \left(\frac{e^{\frac{x i}{2}}-e^{\frac{-x i}{2}}}{i}\right) d x \\
= &\int \ln \left(e^{\frac{x i}{2}}\left(1-e^{-x i}\right)\right) d x-\int \ln i d x\\
= & \frac{x^2 i}{4}+\int \ln \left(1-e^{-x i}\right) d x-\frac{\pi x}{2} i \\
= & \left(\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{\pi x}{2}\right) i-\frac{1}{2} i \operatorname{Li}_2\left(e^{-x i}\right) \\
= & \frac{1}{2} \Im\left(\operatorname{Li}_2\left(e^{-x i}\right)\right)  \textrm{  for real }x .\end{aligned}
$$
Hence
$$\int \ln \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)d x =-x\ln 2+ \frac{1}{2} \Im\left(\operatorname{Li}_2\left(e^{-x i}\right)\right) $$

---

\begin{aligned}
\int \ln (1+\cos x) d x&=\int \ln \left(2 \cos ^2 \frac{x}{2}\right) d x \\
= & \int \ln \left(\frac{\left(2 \cos \frac{x}{2}\right)^2}{2}\right) d x \\
= & 2 \int \ln \left(2 \cos \frac{x}{2}\right) d x-x \ln 2 \\
= & 2 \int \ln \left(e^{\frac{x}{2} i}+e^{-\frac{x}{2} i}\right) d x-x \ln 2 \\
= & 2 \int \ln e^{\frac{x}{2} i} d x+2 \int \ln \left(1+e^{-x i}\right) d x-x \ln 2 \\
= & 2 \Im\left(\operatorname{ Li} _2\left(-e^{-x i}\right)\right)-x \ln 2
\end{aligned}

---

Now we can conclude that

$$\int \ln (1+\sin x-\cos x) d x = 
-\frac{x}{2} \ln 2+\frac{1}{2}\Im\left(\operatorname{ Li} _2\left(e^{-x i}\right)\right)+\Im\left(\operatorname{ Li} _2\left(-e^{-x i}\right)\right)+C
$$
and hence
$$\boxed{\int_0^t \ln (1+\sin x-\cos x) d x = 
-\frac{t}{2} \ln 2+\frac{1}{2}\Im\left(\operatorname{ Li} _2\left(e^{-ti}\right)\right)+\Im\left(\operatorname{ Li} _2\left(-e^{-ti}\right)\right)}
$$
In particular,
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln (1+\sin x-\cos x) d x =  -\frac{\pi}{8} \ln 2+\frac{1}{2} \Im\left(\operatorname{ Li} _2\left(\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)+\Im\left(\operatorname{ Li} _2\left(\frac{i-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)
$$