# Looking to evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm dx\ln^2(1+\sqrt{x})\ln(1-\sqrt{x})$

Tags: calculus

How do I evaluate this integral 
$$\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm dx\ln^2(1+\sqrt{x})\ln(1-\sqrt{x})?$$

Enforcing $x=\tan^2(y)$

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\mathrm dy\sec^2y\tan y\ln^2(1+\tan y)\ln(1-\tan y)$$

Enforcing $v=1+\tan y$

$$\int_{1}^{1+\pi/4}\mathrm dv (v-1)\ln^2(v)\ln(2-v)\tag1$$

$$(1)=\int_{1}^{1+\pi/4} v\ln^2(v)\ln(2-v)\mathrm dv-\int_{1}^{1+\pi/4} \ln^2(v)\ln(2-v)\mathrm dv$$

Comment: You're not going to be able to evaluate this antiderivative in elementary terms. So you're going to have to look for tricks to find the definite integral.

Answer (score 2):

**MY "ANSWER":** I can get you started on the right track using the following two identities:

$$\bbox[lightgray,15px]
{
\int_0^1 x^n\ln(1-x)dx=-\frac{H_{n+1}}{n+1}
}$$

$$\bbox[lightgray,15px]
{
\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n x^{n+1}}{n+1}
}$$

From these, we have
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \ln(1-\sqrt x)\ln^2(1+\sqrt x)
&=\int_0^1 2x\ln(1-x)\ln^2(1+x)dx\\
&=\int_0^1 4x\ln(1-x)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}H_n x^{n+1}}{n+1}dx\\
&=4\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}H_n}{n+1}\int_0^1 x^{n+2}\ln(1-x)dx\\
&=4\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}H_n}{n+1}\frac{H_{n+3}}{n+3}\\
&=4\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}H_nH_{n+3}}{(n+1)(n+3)}
\end{align}$$

This is an [Euler Sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerSum.html) and can probably be computed using some [polylogarithms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html) and a lot of algebra. Euler sums get *really messy* to do by hand, so this is where I abandon the problem and turn to Wolfram.

**WOLFRAM'S ANSWER:** Wolfram evaluates this integral as
$$\int_0^1 \ln(1-\sqrt x)\ln^2(1+\sqrt x)=\frac{11}{4}-\frac{\pi^2}{3}$$
and actually gives an antiderivative:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We are interested in
$$\mathcal{J}= \int_{0}^{1}2x\log^2(1+x)\log(1-x)\,dx$$
and by integration by parts this boils down to computing
$$ \int_{0}^{1}(1+x)\log^2(1+x)\,dx = \frac{3}{4}+2\log^2(2)-2\log(2)$$
$$ \mathcal{K} = \int_{0}^{1}(1-x)\log(1-x)\log(1+x)\,dx$$
and $\mathcal{K}$ can be tackled by enforcing the substitution $x=\cos\theta$ and by exploiting [the Fourier series of $\log\sin$ and $\log \cos$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292468/fourier-series-of-log-sine-and-log-cos). TLDR: an initial step of integration by parts allows to reduce $\mathcal{J}$ from an (alternating) Euler sum with weight $4$ to some Euler sums with weigth $\leq 3$, which [are way more manageable](https://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/FlSa98.pdf). The final outcome is $\mathcal{J}=\frac{11}{4}-2\,\zeta(2)$. We may also integrate by parts twice to reduce the problem to the computation of 
$$ \mathcal{I}_\pm = \int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^2\frac{\log(1\pm x)}{1\mp x}\,dx $$
which is fairly simple (Euler sums with weigth $\leq 2$).