# Proving that $-\frac12[\log(1-e^{2ix})+\log(1-e^{-2ix})]=-\frac12\log(2-2\cos2x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

I was looking at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/292477/583016) and I was confused to see the equality
$$-\frac12\left[\;\log\left(1-e^{2ix}\right)+\log\left(1-e^{-2ix}\right)\;\right]=-\frac12\log(2-2\cos2x)$$
Which I am unable to prove.

I have tried
$$
S=-\frac12\log(1-e^{2ix})-\frac12\log(1-e^{-2ix})=-\frac12\log\frac{1-e^{2ix}}{1-e^{-2ix}}
$$
Then with $u=e^{ix}$:
$$\frac{1-u^2}{1-\frac1{u^2}}=\frac{1-u^2}{1-\frac1{u^2}}\frac{u^2}{u^2}=-u^2\frac{u^2-1}{u^2-1}=-u^2$$
So
$$S=-\frac12\log(-e^{2ix})=-\frac{i\pi}2-ix$$
Which I'm fairly certain is wrong. I'm sure there is something realy simple I'm missing here, could I have some help? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This step is wrong.

> $$S=-\frac12\log(1-e^{2ix})-\frac12\log(1-e^{-2ix})=-\frac12\log\frac{1-e^{2ix}}{1-e^{-2ix}}$$

Correct way:

\begin{align}
-\frac12[\log(1-e^{2ix})+\log(1-e^{-2ix})]&=-\frac12[\log((1-e^{2ix})(1-e^{-2ix}))]\\
&=-\frac12[\log(1-e^{-2ix}-e^{2ix}+1))]\\
&=-\frac12\log(2-2\cos2x)
 \end{align}