# Closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}\zeta(m,n+1)x^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, special-functions, closed-form, zeta-functions

I need a closed form for the following series which appeared when evaluating another sum.
$$S(m,x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}\zeta(m,n+1)x^n, \quad m\in\mathbb{Z}$$

---

I've tried expanding the Hurwitz zeta function by [$(25.11.10)$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11#E10),
$$\zeta(m,n+1)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(m)_{k}}{k!}\zeta(m+k)(-n)^k$$
and switching the order of summation, but the result doesn't look any better.

Any ideas on how to find the generating function?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3344162/generating-function-of-series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-h-nm-binom2nnx) is a post about an equivalent problem.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://www-elsa.physik.uni-bonn.de/%7Edieckman/InfProd/InfProd.html#SeriesxofxZetaxPolyGammaxandxrelated) we have a identity:

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \zeta (m,n+1) x^n=\frac{x \zeta (m)-\text{Li}_m(x)}{1-x}$$
and using the answer from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3344162/generating-function-of-series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-h-nm-binom2nnx) we have:

for any $|x|<\frac{1}{4}$

$$S(m,x)=\\\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \zeta (m,n+1) \binom{2 n}{n} x^n=\\\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left(-\frac{2 \text{Li}_m\left(4 x \cos ^2(t)\right)}{\pi  \left(1-4 x \cos
   ^2(t)\right)}+\frac{8 x \cos ^2(t) \zeta (m)}{\pi  \left(1-4 x \cos ^2(t)\right)}\right) \, dt=\\\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4 x}}-1\right) \zeta (m)-\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \frac{2 \text{Li}_m\left(4 x \cos ^2(t)\right)}{\pi  \left(1-4 x \cos
   ^2(t)\right)} \, dt$$

for the last [integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3344162/generating-function-of-series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-h-nm-binom2nnx) Mathematica can compute for $m=0$ and $m=1$.

Comment: You're overcomplicating things. Your first term should be $$\zeta(m)\left[\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}-1\right]$$ To see this, just write $\zeta(m,n+1)=\zeta(m)-H^{(m)}_n$, and split the series. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\zeta(m)\binom{2n}{n}x^n$ should be your first term (equal to the expression I just gave). Your second term should be the one discussed in the linked answer (equal to that integral).