# $\int\sin^{-1}(x) \frac{x}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)^2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

solve this integral using integral by parts:

$$\int\sin^{-1}(x) \frac{x}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)^2}}\,dx$$

I used substitution :   $\sin^{-1}(x)=t , (so,\sin t=x$), $dt=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$

$$\int t \frac{\sin t}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2t}}\,dt= \int t\tan t\, dt$$
now I need some help to calculate: $\int t\tan t\, dt$

Comment: Not sure there is a closed form [see here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x*tan%28x%29)

Comment: so it seems my approach is not good for this integral

Comment: You will need [polylogs](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x*arcsin%28x%29%2Fsqrt%28%281-x%5E2%29%5E2%29) and a complex analysis approach

Comment: ok but  I'm a freshman at uni, and just know "elementary" functions.

Comment: Was the integral definite?

Comment: No, it is not definite

Comment: and the quesion said: "use integral by parts"

Comment: It shoud be $\int\sin^{-1}(x) \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$. Then it works.

Comment: as the question stands, it does not admit a simple closed form solution which is probably what you are after.

Comment: Thanks, maybe it is the problem of question

Comment: but it is funny, because it is question number 16 and question number 14 is $\int\sin^{-1}(x) \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$ !

Comment: Can you post a picture with the exercise?

Comment: ok I will wait .

Comment: https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/10/15/873007b689062e95eab82c2ca0f4c524-full.png

Comment: Well, my advice would be to not waste time with it then. Very few functions got nice antiderivatives.

Comment: ok thank you for advice I agree with you

Answer (score 1):

There is no "elementary" solution. Once the problem is reduced to the computation of $\int t\tan(t)\,dt$, integration by parts gives that this problem is equivalent to the computation of $\int \log\cos t\,dt$. By [the Fourier series of $\log\cos$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292468/fourier-series-of-log-sine-and-log-cos) we have

$$ \int\log\cos(t)\,dt =C+t\log(2)+\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k^2}\sin(2kt)$$
where
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}\sin(2kt) = \text{Im}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{e^{ki(2t+\pi)}}{k^2} =\text{Im}\,\text{Li}_2\left(-e^{2it}\right)$$
and there's no way to avoid [dilogarithms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html) in the computation of a primitive.
 On the other hand there are special values for particular integration ranges, for instance
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\log\cos(t)\,dt = \frac{K}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\log(2) $$
with $K$ being Catalan's constant, i.e. $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Comment:

$$\int t. tan (t) dt=-t Ln Cos(t)+ \int Ln Cos(t) dt$$

Wolfram alfa says:

$$\int Ln Cos(t) dt=\frac{1}{2}i(Li_2(-e^{2it})+t(t+2i Ln(1+2^{2it})-2it Ln(Cos(t)+ constant$$

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for simple closed form solution

Comment: I doubt that one exists based on this result

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\sin^{-1}(x) \frac{x}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)^2}}dx$$
$\sin^{-1}(x)$=$\cos^{-1} \sqrt{1-x^2}$ ,$\sqrt{1-x^2}=u$,$du= \frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

$$\int \frac{-cos^{-1}(u)}{u}du$$ and we need to calculate this but how?