# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\sin ^2n}{n}$ Is the following solution wrong ?; Does $\sum\frac{(-1)^n\cos 2n}{2n}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\sin ^2n}{n}$$

Solution from the lecture notes :

> $$\frac{(-1)^n\sin ^2n}{n}=\frac{(-1)^n(1-\cos
> > 2n)}{2n}=\frac{(-1)^n}{2n}-\frac{(-1)^n\cos 2n}{2n}$$
> $\frac{(-1)^n}{2n}$ converges conditionally due to Leibniz test.
>
> $\frac{(-1)^n\cos 2n}{2n}$ converges absolutely since $\frac{\cos
> 2n}{2n}$ converges due to Dirichlet test.
>
> We conclude that the sum we started with coverges conditionally.

$\frac{(-1)^n\cos 2n}{2n}$ cannot converge absolutely because
$$\left |\frac{(-1)^n\cos 2n}{2n} \right |=\left |\frac{\cos 2n}{2n} \right |>\frac{\cos^2 2n}{2n}=\frac{\frac12(1+\cos4n)}{2n}=\frac1{4n}+\frac{\cos4n}{4n}$$

This is a sum of a convergent and divergent series hence the series doesn't absolutely  converge.

Am I correct and does $\sum\frac{(-1)^n\cos 2n}{2n}$ converge ?

Comment: I presume $(-1^n)$ should be $(-1)^n$ throughout?

Comment: @AnginaSeng Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dirichlet test with $b_k = \frac{1}{k}$ monotone decreasing and converging to $0$ and $a_k = (-1)^k \sin^2 k$:

$$
S_M = |\sum_{k=1}^{M}(-1)^k \sin^2(k) |\leq |\sum_{k=1}^{M}(-1)^k  | \leq 1\\
$$

Comment: I think OP's question was to find the error in his argument that $\sum\frac{(-1)^n\cos 2n}{2n}$ doesn't converge absolutely.

Comment: Nice solution, anyway

Comment: I don't understand why the first inequality should hold. Is something special about $\sin^2(k)$ used?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\cos(2n) $$
does not converge absolutely but it is conditionally convergent by Dirichlet's test. By cheating a bit in evaluating a power series on the boundary of its region of convergence we have

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\cos(2n)=\text{Re}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-e^{2i})^n}{n}=-\text{Re}\log(1+e^{2i})=\color{red}{\log\left(\frac{\sin 1}{\sin 2}\right)} $$
and this can be turned into an actual proof by invoking summation by parts / Abel's lemma.
It leads to
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\sin^2(n) = \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}\log\cos(1)}$$
and this identity can also be recovered from [the Fourier series of $\log\cos$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292468/fourier-series-of-log-sine-and-log-cos).