# On 'sum of limits is the limit of the sum'

Tags: limits

I am not sure about what happens with this property when the limits are not real numbers, i.e., they exist, but are $\infty$. Say $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = -\infty$. In this case, can we apply the property? Is it true that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) + \lim_{x \to a} g(x) = \lim_{x \to a} \left( f(x)+g(x) \right)$? If it is not, is there any way to deal with such a sum of limits? I'll leave an example from where I asked myself about this.
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - x \right) \ln^2 {x} - \frac{\pi}{2} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^2}$$
I think the result would be $- \infty$ if I could apply this property and bring them into a single limit, but I wasn't sure about that as they both are $\infty$ so that's why I'm asking.

Comment: What does $L \to+ \infty$ mean ?? Do you mean that $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = +\infty$ ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe The limit approaches $\infty$, something like a vertical assymptote

Comment: Limits are fixed things. They approach nothing.

Comment: Ok, so you mean that the limit **is** $+\infty$.

Comment: Sorry for bad use of words and concepts. I updated the question, I hope it's better

Comment: $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) \pm \lim_{x \to a} g(x) = \lim_{x \to a} \left( f(x)\pm g(x) \right)$ is a property of limits. There is no exception. Check https://www.math24.net/properties-limits/#:~:text=This%20rule%20states%20that%20the,%E2%86%92ag(x).

Comment: @DatBoi But I don't know if the property applies when both limits are $\infty$, not real numbers

Comment: Well, the sum of a quantity that tends to $+\infty$ and a quantity that tends to $-\infty$, can have a finite limit, or an infinite limit, or no limit at all. It is what we call an *indeterminate form*. Therefore you are not allowed to apply a rule such "the sum of the limit is the limit of the sum".

Comment: @DatBoi To write such an equality, you have to be sure that all the limits exist ! But the fact that the RHS has a limit is not always true, given that the limits of the LHS exist.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Of course!! Both limits must be defined!

Comment: @DatBoi If you apply the rule with infinite limits, you can conclude things like $\infty - \infty = 2$ or $\infty - \infty = 3$. It is really sloppy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=-\infty,$$then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\bigl(f(x)+g(x)\bigr)$ can be *anything*. For instance, if $b\in\Bbb R$, if $f(x)=\frac1{(x-a)^2}+b$ and if $g(x)=-\frac1{(x-a)^2}$, then$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty,\ \lim_{x\to a}g(x)=-\infty\text{ and }\lim_{x\to a}\bigl(f(x)+g(x)\bigr)=b.$$

Comment: But you did apply the limit sum property in order to conclude that, I mean you did $\lim_{x \to a} \left( \frac{1}{(x-a)^2} + b \right) + \lim_{x \to a} - \frac{1}{(x-a)^2} = \lim_{x \to a} \left(  \frac{1}{(x-a)^2} + b - \frac{1}{(x-a)^2} \right) = \lim_{x \to a} b = b$

Comment: No, I did not! **Where**, in my answer, do you see the first equality of your comment?

Comment: Sorry I wrongly assumed you were answering my question. I wondered if I could do something with the first part that I wrote, the sum of the two limits

Comment: But I **did* answer your question. I told you that, from the knowledge that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$ and that $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=-\infty$, you get *no information whatsoever* about $\lim_{x\to a}\bigl(f(x)+g(x)\bigr)$.

Comment: The thing I didn't understand is, do we just let $\lim_{x \to a} \left( \frac{1}{(x-a)^2} + b \right) + \lim_{x \to a} - \frac{1}{(x-a)^2}$ undefined then? I'm sorry if I'm not understanding correctly

Comment: Yes, $\infty-\infty$ is undefined.

Comment: It's hard for me to grasp it. I got to the example I wrote in the question from an integral, and it turns out that this sum of limits should be zero in order for my integral to make sense. What can I do about it? Do I just look for a different technique which does not involve ending up with such undefined expressions?

Comment: The expression$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - x \right) \ln^2 {x} - \frac{\pi}{2} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^2}$$doesn't make sense. Where did you get it from?

Comment: I got it after doing some substitutions. I originally wrote another question about the integral but it seems I didn't explain my problem well because I only got answers on how to solve the integral, which wasn't what I wanted. You can check the process here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3812962/804320

Comment: It's the same problem all over again. The expression$$\left.x \log^2\left({\cos{x}} \right) \right|_0^{\pi/2} +2 \int_0^{\pi/2} x \tan x \log\left(\cos x\right)\,\mathrm dx$$doesn't make sense, since it is $\infty-\infty$.

Comment: So a simple integration by parts fails because I ended up writing a number (convergent integral) as $\infty - \infty$ which doesn't make sense. Then, am I only allowed to do this if the result of the integration by parts is a sum of two real numbers?

Comment: Or if you get $\infty+\infty$. Or $-\infty-\infty$. Or if one of them is $\pm\infty$ and the other one is a real number.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you very much for your time. Now it makes sense. Have a nice day!

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Sorry I forgot about that option, I'm new. It was useful, I marked it now