# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x\ln\left(\tan x\right)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, closed-form, residue-calculus

> Evaluate  $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x\ln\left(\tan x\right)\,dx$$

First we will work out the complex integral of the function $$\displaystyle{f\left( z \right) = \frac{{{z^2}}}{{{e^z} - 1}},{\text{ }}z \ne 0} and \displaystyle{f\left( 0 \right) = 0}$$ in the rectangle $\displaystyle{c:{\text{ }}OABC}$ with $$\displaystyle{O\left( {0,0} \right){\text{, }}A\left( {R,0} \right){\text{, }}B\left( {R,i \pi } \right){\text{ \& }}D\left( {i\pi ,0} \right)}$$ Obviously f(z) is analytic without poles in the above rectangle, so  $\displaystyle{\int\limits_c {f\left( z \right)dz}  = 0}$
[image]
For
$$\displaystyle{z = R + iy{\text{  with  }}y \in \left[ {0,\pi } \right]:\mathop {\lim }\limits_{R \to \infty } \left| {f\left( z \right)} \right| = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{R \to \infty } \left| {\frac{{{{\left( {R + iy} \right)}^2}}}{{{e^{R + iy}} - 1}}} \right| \leqslant \mathop {\lim }\limits_{R \to \infty } \frac{{\left| {{{\left( {R + iy} \right)}^2}} \right|}}{{{e^R} - 1}}\xrightarrow{{R \to  + \infty }}0}$$
And
$$\displaystyle{0 = \int\limits_c {f\left( z \right)dz}  = \int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{{x^2}}}{{{e^x} - 1}}dx}  + \int\limits_\infty ^0 {\frac{{{{\left( {x + i\pi } \right)}^2}}}{{{e^{x + i\pi }} - 1}}dx}  + i \cdot \int\limits_\pi ^0 {\frac{{{{\left( {iy} \right)}^2}}}{{{e^{iy}} - 1}}dy}  \Rightarrow }$$
$$\displaystyle{ \Rightarrow \int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{{x^2}}}{{{e^x} - 1}}dx}  + \int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{{x^2}}}{{{e^x} + 1}}dx}  - {\pi ^2}\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{e^x} + 1}}dx}  + 2i\pi \int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{x}{{{e^x} + 1}}dx}  - i \cdot \int\limits_\pi ^0 {\frac{{{y^2}}}{{\cos \left( y \right) - 1 + i\sin \left( y \right)}}dy}  = 0}$$

$$\displaystyle{\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{e^x} + 1}}dx}  = \int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{{e^{ - x}}}}{{1 + {e^{ - x}}}}dx}  =  - \left[ {\ln \left( {1 + {e^{ - x}}} \right)} \right]_0^\infty  = \ln \left( 2 \right)}$$
$$\displaystyle{\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{x}{{{e^x} + 1}}dx}  = \int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{x{e^{ - x}}}}{{1 + {e^{ - x}}}}dx}  = \int\limits_0^\infty  {x\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{k + 1}}{e^{ - kx}}} } \right)dx}  = \sum\limits_1^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{k + 1}}\int\limits_0^\infty  {x{e^{ - kx}}dx} }  = \sum\limits_1^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{k + 1}}}}{{{k^2}}}}  = .. = \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{{12}}}$$
$$\displaystyle{\int\limits_\pi ^0 {\frac{{{y^2}}}{{\cos \left( y \right) - 1 + i\sin \left( y \right)}}dy}  = \int\limits_0^\pi  {\frac{{{y^2}}}{{2{{\sin }^2}\left( {\dfrac{y}{2}} \right) - 2i \cdot \sin \left( {\dfrac{y}{2}} \right)\cos \left( {\dfrac{y}{2}} \right)}}dy}  = \int\limits_0^\pi  {\frac{{{y^2}}}{{ - 2i\sin \left( {\dfrac{y}{2}} \right)\left( {\cos \left( {\dfrac{y}{2}} \right) + i\sin \left( {\dfrac{y}{2}} \right)} \right)}}dy}  = }$$

$$\displaystyle{ = \frac{i}{2} \cdot \int\limits_0^\pi  {\frac{{{y^2}\left( {\cos \left( {\dfrac{y}{2}} \right) - i\sin \left( {\dfrac{y}{2}} \right)} \right)}}{{\sin \left( {\dfrac{y}{2}} \right)}}dy}  = \frac{i}{2} \cdot \int\limits_0^\pi  {\frac{{{y^2}}}{{\tan \left( {\dfrac{y}{2}} \right)}}dy}  + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \int\limits_0^\pi  {{y^2}dy}  = \mathop  = \limits^{y/2 = x}  = 4i \cdot \int\limits_0^{\pi /2} {\frac{{{x^2}}}{{\tan \left( x \right)}}dx}  + \frac{{{\pi ^3}}}{6}}$$

Comment: I also don't think that Integration By Parts will work here. Take $u=x$ and $v=\ln(\tan(x))$.  But then also try once. Though I am not sure.

Comment: @SyamaprasadChakrabarti You actually can make integration by parts work if you know your Clausen functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function#Integral_evaluations_involving_the_direct_function

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution without complex analysis.

First, one can show by substituting the [Fourier series of $\log\sin x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292468/fourier-series-of-log-sine-and-log-cos) in the following integrals and integrating term by term that

$$I_1=\int_0^{\pi/2}dx 
\log\sin x=-\frac{\pi}{2}\log2$$

$$I_2=\int_0^{\pi/2}dx ~x\log \sin x=\frac{7\zeta(3)}{16}-\frac{\pi^2}{8}\log2$$

Finally, note that the integral in question can be written

$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}dx ~ x\log \sin x-\int_0^{\pi/2}dx ~ x\log \cos x=2I_2-\frac{\pi}{2}I_1$$

via the substitution $x\to \pi/2-x$ in the second integral. This yields

$$I=\frac{7\zeta(3)}{8}$$

Comment: It should be $\frac{7\zeta(3)}{8}$

Comment: Thanks, it was just a typo.